# PHP Encoding and Decoding HTML as Binary

Tags: php, html, postgresql, base64

The database I am using is Postgresql and I downloading a webpage and storing in a BLOB. Like this:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
$encoded_html = base64_encode($html);

//Store encoded data in blob in database
?>
```

That part works fine. But when I try to decode it and display it, it comes out garabled.

```
<?php echo base64_decode($encoded_html); ?>
```

Do I have to add extra parameters when encoding and decoding the data?

Comment: why you want to encode? it takes 33% more memory!

Comment: Besides that if you are base64 encoding then you don't need a blob, just plain text.

Comment: Indeed, take care of the place used by base64. it is greedy of memory. You can add directly your content, escaping your string to prevent error from your postGreSQL. That will be fine and more simple.

Comment: were you able to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If this works then the encode/decode functions work fine

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
$md5 = md5($html);
$encoded_html = base64_encode($html);
$decoded_html = base64_decode($encoded_html);
echo (md5($decoded_html) == $md5) ? 'OK' : 'FAIL';
echo PHP_EOL;
```

If not then I'd suggest comparing the base64 data that you're putting into the database with what comes out.